# Kubernetes/kubectl: unable to connect to a server to handle "pods"

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, orchestration

I'm new to Kubernetes so I encountered the following issue. These are my steps:

1) I ran `etcd`:

```
docker run --volume=/var/etcd:/var/etcd --net=host -d gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.12 /usr/local/bin/etcd --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 --data-dir=/var/etcd/data
```

2) I ran the master container:

```
docker run \
--volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
--volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
--volume=/dev:/dev \
--volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
--volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
--volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
--net=host \
--pid=host \
--privileged=true \
-d gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1 \
/hyperkube kubelet --containerized --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" --address="0.0.0.0" --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests
```

3) I ran the proxy:

```
docker run -d --net=host --privileged gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1 /hyperkube proxy --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --v=2
```

4) I installed `kubectl`

5) I created this simple `pod-file.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

and tried to create pod by running:

```
kubectl create -f pod-file.yml
```

And I got:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ kubectl create -f pod-file.yml
error: could not read an encoded object from pod-file.yml: unable to connect to a server to handle "pods": couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
```

I found it pretty odd so I checked containers I ran earlier:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                                                           PORTS               NAMES
3ae7f094bb01        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1   "/hyperkube proxy ..."   55 minutes ago      Up 55 minutes                                                                                        suspicious_ramanujan
ed841bc6ef26        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1   "/hyperkube kubele..."   57 minutes ago      Up 57 minutes                                                                                        competent_mclean
7408c640a2c8        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.12        "/usr/local/bin/et..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                                                     elated_shaw
```

So looks like all is ok because all containers are up and running. Okay, I checked open ports in my system (`ubuntu 16.04`):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -nautp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1315/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3209/etcd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3324/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3399/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3209/etcd
tcp        0    524 172.30.3.114:22         212.98.179.158:35900    ESTABLISHED 3087/sshd: ubuntu [
tcp6       0      0 :::10255                :::*                    LISTEN      3324/hyperkube
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1315/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::4001                 :::*                    LISTEN      3209/etcd
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      3324/hyperkube
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           959/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           796/dhclient
```

And I found that there is no `8080` open TCP port that `kubectl` tried to reach. So this is the cause of my issue.

So my question is what container/service/daemon I should run/launch to open this port and to assign web service to it in order to let kubectl use it for this GET request `http://localhost:8080/api`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that really all that is needed to run Kubernetes? Are you able to run `kubectl version` and get the version of the client and cluster? I think there are many more components needed for a working Kubernetes cluster (such as the AP servers, controller, and scheduler).

Comment: in which OS are you running these commands? Anyway, I recommend you to start by using minikube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a [kubernetes cluster from scratch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/) is a little more complicated. The master `kubelet` runs a [number of pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/#apiserver-controller-manager-and-scheduler) to make it all go.

If you're looking for an all in one solution use [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) to run in a VM. Otherwise use [`kubeadm`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) to setup your master and work back from there if you want to see how each component is setup.